# how to deal with a string with regex

Tags: java, regex

for example: 
I have a string like this:
http://shop.vipshop.com/detail-97996-12358781.html

I want to use regex  to find 97996   and  12358781
java code is appreciated
Many thanks.

```
    String str="http://shop.vipshop.com/detail-97996-12358781.html";
    String regex ="\-d{5}\-";
    Pattern pattern  = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

but it was wrong

Comment: You are come from china？

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String str="http://shop.vipshop.com/detail-97996-12358781.html";
String regex =".*detail-(\\d+)-(\\d+).html";
Pattern pattern  = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if(matcher.matches()){
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + "|" + matcher.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to invoke either [`Matcher#find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) or [`Matcher#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) to actually get the matches.  In this case, you would need the former one, as you are only finding a part of string matching the regex.

And you can use `+` quantifier to get any length of digit. Try using this:

```
String regex ="\\d+";
Pattern pattern  = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two lines:

```
String num1 = str.replaceAll(".*-(\\d+)-.*", "$1");
String num2 = str.replaceAll(".*-(\\d+)\\..*", "$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "http://shop.vipshop.com/detail-97996-12358781.html";
String regex = "(?<=detail-)(\\d+)-(\\d+)(?=\\.html)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
```

output:

`97996` `12358781`

Answer (score 0):

You have used a quantifier (5) and still the 1235... is 8 characters long?
Is it always 5 and 8 can you use:

```
"([\\d]{5,8})"
```

The matches captured into backreferences

But if you need to find in the specific form detail-NUMBER-NUMBER.html you can use:

```
"detail-([\\d]*)-([\\d]*).html"
```

The matches captured in [1] and [2]

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
String str="http://shop.vipshop.com/detail-97996-12358781.html";
    String regex ="[^0-9]+([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+).+";
    Pattern pattern  = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    if(matcher.matches()){
       System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " " + matcher.group(2));
    }
```

for advance tutorial go to this link

[RegEx tutorial](http://regexone.com/)

and [Regular Expression tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
if(matcher.find()){

}
```

on

```
System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

then your code is:

```
String str="http://shop.vipshop.com/detail-97996-12358781.html";
String regex ="\\d{5,}";
Pattern pattern  = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if(matcher.find()){
   System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```